# I keep getting an error message of i use an else function in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the PHP block i am using:

```
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];

$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$un = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswd = "";
$pswd2 = "";
$d = "";
$u_check = "";

$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); //Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {}
if ($em==$em2){}
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
$check = mysql_num_rows ($u_check);
if ($check == 0){}
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2){}
if ($pswd==$pswd2){}
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25){
echo "The maximum amount of character is 25! Please try again";
}
else
{
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){}
echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln',   
'$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
}
```

And here is the two else statements:

```
else
{
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){}
echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln',   
'$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
}
```

When i only have:

```
else
{
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){}
echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
```

I don't get an error message, but when i add:

```
else
{
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
}
```

I get this error message when i refresh:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 39

I am using a YouTube tutorial, and this is what he typed, he didn't get an error message. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgqVNMTnmDQ&list=PLA7F9875BD031DC16&index=36

This video was done in 2013.

If someone could help me, it would be appreciated.

Comment: you arent closing your tags fully. That could be why. horrible code formatting so difficult to see...

Comment: use a code editor and you'll see where your logic is failing

Comment: What do you mean i'm not closing my tags fully?

Comment: What code editor do you recommend? I'm using brackets

Comment: this isn't a live or "intended to go live" site, is it?

Comment: I'm wanting to make it live @Fred-ii-

Comment: Would you be interested in helping me to make this website?@Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if`s are wrong the `{` opens the control block and the `}` closes it. For example with this:

```
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){}
```

You are doing nothing when the password is longer than 30 characters or less than 5. (also why limit passwords to 30 characters?)

You also then are echoing the message regardless of that condition:

```
echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
```

Additional notes:

Your control blocks should be indented.

You should NOT put user data directly into a SQL query. That is how injections occur. `strip_tags` does nothing to stop a SQL injection.

Try:

```
<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$un = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswd = "";
$pswd2 = "";
$d = "";
$u_check = "";
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);//dont use @, no need for error supression, resolve the errors.
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); //Year - Month - Day
if ($reg) {}//does nothing
if ($em==$em2){}//does nothing
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
$check = mysql_num_rows ($u_check);
if ($check == 0){}//does nothing
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2){}//does nothing
if ($pswd==$pswd2){}//does nothing
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25){
    echo "The maximum amount of character is 25! Please try again";
} else {
    if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){
        echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
    } else {
        $pswd = md5($pswd); //should upgrade hashing algorithm
        $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);//not used
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln',   
        '$em','$pswd','$d','0')");//open to SQL injections
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really confused

Comment: I still get this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 37

Comment: It's working, thank you.

Comment: sure hope this isn't a live site ;-)

Comment: It's not live yet, i want to at least finish and then make it live.

Comment: I'm kind of looking for people to help me with this website. So, would you be interested? I don't mind if your not.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking to me or @Fred-ii-, (using @s helps direct comments). I don't have enough time to assist further, sorry.

Comment: I was talking to you @chris85